# How do I program different languages in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, text-editor

I recently downloaded Sublime Text, but I could only find 9 languages, all of which I don't program. I would like to code HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and I would like to know how to add these build systems onto my computer.

Comment: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools) is a good source when starting out in these things.  Learn HTML first, then look at CSS and JavaScript.  The three are very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SublimeText is just a text editor with some 'extra bits' plugged in.

HTML, CSS and JavaScript aren't compiled languages, so you don't need a compiler, just save the file with the correct extention (.html, .cs or .js).

For syntax highlighting, click the box on the far right of the status bar, it'll list some languages that SublimeText knows about, including those three and will helpfully provide syntax colouring and formatting to help you along.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text is only a text editor. As for HTML, CSS, and JS, those are all present in sublime, and don't require a build system, just a web browser.

If you want to use those languages, use shift-command(control?)-p to open the command pallet and type sshtml, sscss, ssjavascript, etc. to set the syntax highlighting.

To run it, simply open the HTML file in your browser, and reload the page if you've made changes.